# PHP exec() not returning

Tags: php

I am writing a PHP script that will launch a program on the server.

I do so with:

```
exec('myAppName');
```

This line of code "works" in that it actually executes the program, however, I can't get the it to return (continue past) from this line.

It will just hang there, until I either manually close the program that was opened or the max_execution_time is exceeded.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Did you want to `fork` and then `exec`? Because `exec` isn't supposed to somehow "background" the process.

Comment: Shot in the dark but try using [`passthru()`](http://php.net/passthru) instead of `exec()`. The output of the program might reveal something.

Comment: Tried passthru() as well with the same result.

Comment: I should have stated that I am running the PHP on a Windows Server.

Anyway, I used a tool called "PsExec" to launch the process and not wait on it.

    exec("psexec -d myAppName");

This appears to accomplish what I needed.

Comment: Adam, you can accomplish that on Windows without the need for any external programs: http://ss64.com/nt/start.html

Comment: Westie, this does not appear to let you run it in the background though.  It has the same affect as just using exec(), in that it hangs until termination.

Comment: You're doing it wrong then! :) I use this: `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C start /D {$sDirectory} /B {$sBinaryName}` ...and works fine for me and a couple of hundred of people who use my game control panels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To background a process in PHP, you'll need to do something like this:

```
function spawnBackgroundProcess($sProcessLine)
{
    $aPipes = array();

    $rProcess = proc_open($sProcessLine, array(), $aPipes);
    proc_close($rProcess);
}
```

Really that's abusing the proc_* family, but it's the best way sadly.

(Don't forget the &!)

Answer (score 1):

The [manual for `exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), while not being entirely clear on the matter of waiting for the launched program to exit, states the return value to be

> Return values: The last line from the result of the command.

In other words, just as you're observing, in order to return the last line output, `exec` won't return until the launched program exits.

Answer (score 0):

You need to background it in order to continue with the rest of the php I believe.

In Unix/Linux, use the "&" character. ..

Hm or is that System that does that .. damn, cant remember now - will go read the manual again.

Comment: I should have stated in the original post, but I am on a Windows Server.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute a command in the background without having the script waiting for the result, you can do the following:

```
<?php
passthru("/usr/bin/php /path/to/script.php ".$argv_parameter." >> /path/to/log_file.log        2>&1 &");
?>
```

There are a few thing that are important here.

First of all: put the full path to the php binary, because this command will run under the apache user, and you will probably not have command alias like php set in that user.

Seccond: Note 2 things at the end of the command string: the '2>&1' and the '&'. The '2>&1' is for redirecting errors to the standard IO. And the most important thing is the '&' at the end of the command string, which tells the terminal not to wait for a response.

Third: Make sure you have 777 permissions on the 'log_file.log' file

Enjoy!