# exec() with php command does not return any value

Tags: php, exec, html

What actually i want to do is to get contents from the winword file in my web page. 
for this purpose i used the **exec()** method, i also tried the following code:

```
$pCom = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$pShell = $pCom->exec("Notepad.exe");
$sStdOut = $pShell->StdOut->ReadAll;    # Standard output
$sStdErr = $pShell->StdErr->ReadAll;    # Error
echo($sStdOut);
```

the above code through an Exception that:

```
 Fatal error: Class 'COM' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\test\tests\Notepad.php on line 9
```

I have no idea what to do and how to do this?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299809/php-exec-not-returning and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114574/php-exec-does-not-return-output

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues with your approach:

1. a text editor does not output text written in it when closing the editor. So why would you expect to receive the text when firing the editor by means of an `exec()` call?
2. you miss understood how the `exec()` command actually works, I assume you did not really read the documentation of the [`exec() function`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.exec.php) which clearly states that the return value of an executed command is *the last line of its output*. That is not what you want.